# How do I annotate TIFF images with text without having to plot the images, in R?

Tags: r, tiff

I have several hundred TIFFs in a directory and I would like to annotate with text. Online solutions I've found involve displaying the image then using the text function. But I'd prefer not to display the TIFFs. The magick package has the image_annotate function, but the magick package seems unable to preserve my original 32 bit depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot directly to the output file, without displaying.

```
library(tiff)
Image = as.raster(readTIFF("Temp/RLogo.tif"))
tiff("Temp/LabeledRLogo.tif")
plot(Image)
text(40,15, labels="This is a label")
dev.off()
```

Resulting image:

[image: Labeled R logo]